# Can't alter the code in visual code studio for flutter/dart using android virtual device

Tags: android, flutter, dart, virtual, device

a newbie here

My OS is Windows 10

Recently started to follow a tutorial on "flutter mobile development for beginners"

The tutorial is about 1 to 2 years old

Followed every path, installed git>flutter>android studio>updated the path in user console variables>created android virtual device(installed flutter and dart extensions)>virtual studio code(installed flutter and dart extensions)

The problem is whenever I try to change the code within the Virtual Code Studio, and press "hot reload" in cmd the app in virtual device does not recognize the changes and nothing happens

However, I am able to change the code within the android studio itself and continue my tutorial, but at this point I just want to understand what am I doing wrong and to find the solution for this issue

Note that, there are no errors showing when I run the "flutter doctor" command, and
Visual Code Studio does see the virtual device in right-left corner and even enables me to run the virtual device within itself without requiring me to open first android studio to run AVD

Big thanks in advance

Comment: It could be an VS Code issue, try this https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/60872#issuecomment-731617046

Comment: did you make sure you save your code in VS code ? try also to do hot restart by pressing capital R, not hot reload (small r)

Comment: @ammar thats right, problem solved. In VS code>file>auto-save(check), resolved the problem. Now "hot reload" does the job